# Azure Functions Core tools doesn't support Node LTS Version 12.X

Tags: azure-functions

Per the Azure Functions Core Tools Documentation an LTS-covered major version (ex: 8.11.1 or 10.14.1). LTS-covered 
versions have an even major version number (8.x, 10.x, etc.) is required to run Functions locally. However I have 12.13.0 installed and it won't run. Any updates or workarounds ?

Comment: Any update on this issue? If my answer could help you, please accept it.

Comment: Check the new comment about azure function with node v12 .https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues/200#issuecomment-555144911

Answer (score 0):

For now this is not supported and no announcements about support for latest LTS node version.

You could check this issue:[Node.js v12 support](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-nodejs-worker/issues/200), and there is a comment:

> Active LTS for node 12 starts on 10/21, and we won't have an Active LTS version deployed and ready to use until November

And even now is already November, it doesn't mention node 12 in the [official announcements](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/labels/azure-functions) about function.